Member detection within a class
Needed to do some Meta programming.
I needed to check if a class has a specific member (one case a member variable second case a member type (two distinct use cases)).
Since I am writing a library, I don't know the types. The classes will be provided by the user of the library (the mongo stuff I asked for a review earlier) hence using meta programming to detect.
I figured out a way (lots of googling and some old code). I could not find anything newer (or standard library classes). Any input will be helpful.
Though the techniques are basically the same for both cases I will provide both there.
// Check if the type has a member `_id`.
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  struct HasID
  {
      using One = char;
      struct Two { char x[2]; };

      template <typename C> static One testHasID( decltype(C::_id)* );
      template <typename C> static Two testHasID(...);

      static constexpr bool val = sizeof(testHasID<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
  };    

  // Check if there is a type member called `CType`
  template<typename T>
  struct HasCType
  {
      using One = char;
      struct Two { char x[2]; };

      template <typename C> static One testHasType(typename C::CType*);
      template <typename C> static Two testHasType(...);

      static constexpr bool val = sizeof(testHasType<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
  };
}

The tests:
  #include "gtest/gtest.h"

  #include "ThorsMongo.h"

  struct NoID
  {
      int         value;
  };
  struct YesID
  {
      ObjectID    _id;
      int         value;
  };

  TEST(HasIDTest, NoID)
  {
      EXPECT_FALSE(HasID<NoID>::val);
  }

  TEST(HasIDTest, YesID)
  {
      EXPECT_TRUE(HasID<YesID>::val);
  }

  struct NoType
  {
      using V = int;
  };
  struct YesType
  {
      using CType = int;
  };

  TEST(HasTypeTest, NoID)
  {
      EXPECT_FALSE(HasCType<NoType>::val);
  }

  TEST(HasTypeTest, YesType)
  {
      EXPECT_TRUE(HasCType<YesType>::val);
  }


This is not for C++20 (concepts) or even C++17 (void_t)?

@indi Technically I have set the flag -std=c++20. But open to suggestions specific for C++17 and C++20. Including how to use concepts (still struggling with them).

Pre C++20 concepts
I know you are using C++20 (as everyone should; C++23 is the current version, and C++26 already has its first major features), but just for completeness I thought I’d give a pre-C++20 review because there are still many people stuck on C++17.
Your current code is correct (so far as I can tell), and as of C++14, it would be the “right” way to do this. But as of C++17, the preferred way to make type traits is using std::void_t.
Let’s look at a comparison of the two methods:
template<typename T>
struct HasID
{
    using One = char;
    struct Two { char x[2]; };

    template <typename C> static One testHasID( decltype(C::_id)* );
    template <typename C> static Two testHasID(...);

    static constexpr bool val = sizeof(testHasID<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
};

// vs:

template <typename, typename = void>
struct HasID : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct HasID<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::_id)>> : std::true_type {};

The void_t version is not only significantly shorter, it is also much easier to understand. Yes, it now requires two types (or rather, one type and one specialization), but that actually makes more logical sense. The base type is the “default”, and the specialization is the actual detector. Done this way, it is much clearer that “false” is the default, and the special case is “true” (as opposed to the default case being “true”, and the specialization being “false”).
And things would be even clearer with more advanced detection traits. For example, instead of just inheriting from true_type or false_type, you could compose traits by inheriting from conditinal_t or conjugation or whatever else.
Plus it is a lot easier to explain. “void_t is void only if all of its arguments are defined, otherwise it is nothing. When it is void, the specialization matches, and specializations always take priority. When it is nothing, it falls back to the base case.” See? Simple.
Meanwhile, the C++14 way is not only harder to understand (it is much harder to spot whether the “default” is true or false, for example), it is extremely hard to compose complex traits, and it is even surprisingly hard to get the simple case correct. This is what you did:
    using One = char;
    struct Two { char x[2]; };

… which is correct (because sizeof(One) will always be 1, and sizeof(Two) will always be 2, so they can never be equal). But I have seem many people do something like this:
    using One = char;
    using Two = int;

… which… “works” on virtually every system most people will ever use, but is not correct. (Because sizeof(int) can be 2, 4, or… yes… even 1, so sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) may be true, which breaks everything.)
The modern way
As of C++20, using SFINAE is mostly obsolete. Even when making a type trait, you should use requires rather than SFINAE. As in:
template <typename T>
struct HasID : std::bool_constant<requires { T::_id; }> {};

Even though there is a single template, it is still very clear what is going on; clearer than both the C++14 SFINAE and C++17 void_t methods. And it is much, much, much more powerful.
Now, at this point, I would point to some guidelines, or even just an article or blog post on best practices for using concepts and type traits. Unfortunately… I don’t think anyone’s actually written a comprehensive one yet. You can find guidelines scattered about, often as asides in articles about other stuff. And there are a few good guidelines in the Core Guidelines. But there is no canonical resource for best practices that gives a really good big-picture view.
So I’m going to have to take a swing at making one, right here. Just, please, keep a few things in mind:

This is being put together on the fly, by the seat of my pants. It will almost certainly have errors.
It has not been peer-reviewed.
It does not represent expert consensus.

Hopefully some expert out there will take this as a challenge, and maybe even a starting point, for a more comprehensive set of guidelines about concepts and type traits in C++20 and beyond.
Let’s give this a shot.
1. Always prefer concepts over type traits…
Concepts, at least from a functional perspective, completely obsolete type traits. (Concepts don’t obsolete type traits from a design/theoretical perspective, but we’ll get to that later.) Everything type traits can do, concepts can do better. They are easier to write, easier to understand, and have powers that type traits can only dream of.
Let’s consider the two type traits you are making. You can see how much code it takes using the C++14 SFINAE method. Here is what they look like with void_t:
template <typename, typename = void>
struct HasID : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct HasID<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::_id)>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename = void>
struct HasCType : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct HasCType<T, std::void_t<typename C::CType>> : std::true_type {};

And here is what they would look like as concepts:
template <typename T>
concept HasID = requires { T::_id; };

template <typename T>
concept HasCType = requires { typename C::CType; };

You can’t get much easier to write than that. There is pretty much nowhere you can make an error there. Even in the void_t case, you could mix up true_type and false_type, or make a copypasta mistake and put true_type for both cases. With the concepts version, I mean, you can mispell CType, I guess, but you can make that mistake in every version. Putting aside mistakes you can make in every version, there is virtually no mistake you can make in the concepts case that won’t trigger a compile error.
And you can’t get much easier to understand than that. Even someone who doesn’t know concepts can quite easily guess what is going on there.
And concepts have super powers that type traits do not: most notably, the power of subsumption.
I’m not going to go into detail about subsumption yet; I’ll just give a quick example. With type traits, when you want to specialize on a trait, you need to explicitly describe both the positive and negative cases:
template <typename T>
auto f() -> std::enable_if_t<not std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>;

template <typename T>
auto f() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>;

This can be a massive pain the ass. If you have an algorithm that works fine for the general case, but then you can make an optimized version if the type is default constructible (for example), then you need to go back to the base case, and add the contra-case. That’s a pain for just one constraint. Now try it for several, with multiple specializations.
But thanks to subsumption, that is not a problem with concepts:
template <typename T>
auto f();

template <typename T>
requires std::default_initializable<T>
auto f();

This works, because the second function’s constraints subsume the first function’s constraints (well, there are none in this case, but yanno). And as you can see, you don’t need to touch the base case. (In fact, it would be wrong to add a not std::default_initializable<T> constraint to the base case. That would break the ordering, which doesn’t cause a problem here, but would in more complex cases.)
So you should always use concepts instead of type traits as of C++20…
… except…
1(b). … unless you are literally just testing for type features
One guideline about concepts that has been widely agreed upon is that concepts should be about semantics, not syntax. We’ll actually get to that in a second. However, that would mean that your current type traits should not be concepts. Both “has an _id static data member” and “has a CType nested type” are semantically meaningless.
So if you were just interested in making a tool to detect the presence of an _id static data member or CType nested type, then I would say: stick with type traits. You can still use requires to define the type trait. The standard pattern for type traits is:
template <typename T>
struct HasID : std::bool_constant<requires { T::_id; }> {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto HasID_v = HasID<T>::value;

Is some cases it might make more sense to define the constant, and then define the type trait type in terms of that.
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto HasID_v = requires { T::_id; };

template <typename T>
struct HasID : std::bool_constant<HasID_v<T>> {};

There might be compilation time benefits from that in some cases. If you have a large amount of type traits, you can try profiling both ways.
So type traits haven’t been completely obsoleted in C++20 and beyond. But they have been massively downsized in importance. I would say that in C++20 and beyond, you should think of type traits as building blocks, rarely to be used by themselves, but rather mostly used to construct more complex concepts.
If your library wanted or needed to expose the ability to detect _id static data members (or CType member types) as part of the user-facing API for whatever reason, then type traits would be the way to go, even in C++20 and beyond.
2. Concepts should be about semantics, not syntax
The canonical example of a bad concept is:
template <typename T>
concept addable = requires(T a, T b) { a + b; };

Concepts are super powerful, and thus should be used very carefully. It doesn’t make a lot of sense to make concepts for every piddly little thing, not least because you’ll end up with lots of incompatible overlap:
// Library 1
template <typename T>
concept addable = requires(T a, T b) { a + b; };

// Library 2
template <typename T>
concept has_plus = requires(T a, T b) { a + b; };

The mere presence of the binary + operator is… meaningless. The same syntax is used in wildly different ways. Sometimes it is for mathematical addition. Sometimes it is for concatenation.
This is why you should not write concepts with a focus on mere syntax. Instead you should focus on semantics.
The way I have been describing this (and I’m still workshopping the wording) is: Concepts should describe what a type is, not what it has or does.
Once you know what a type is, conceptually, then you know what interface it should have. Then you write the concept describing that interface. But the key thing to understand is that you are really describing is a “concept”—a “notion”—of a thing… not a set of syntax. The syntax you expect merely follows from the conceptual notion you are considering.
So addable and has_plus are bad concepts. But number would be a good concept. If you imagine a function auto add(number auto a, number auto b) { return a + b; }, number is a much more logical description of the kind of types you want than merely has_plus or addable, because (presumably) number would accept all conceivable number types, but reject strings (so add(string1, string2) wouldn’t incorrectly concatenate the strings… concatenation is not “adding”).
(It’s unfortunate that the standard library has so many of these poor concepts, like copyable and such. But it makes sense, and is even unavoidable, because the standard library is, by design, both very low-level and very generic. There is no semantic requirement on the types for std::copy() other than “they can be copied”. But this is not true for pretty much any other library. Most libraries are not both low-level and generic.)
So your two type traits should not be converted to concepts. They have no semantic meaning. They would be fine if left as type traits.
But let’s consider the bigger picture. I don’t think what I just described is what you really want. I don’t think you really want just a pair of type traits for detecting _id static data members and CType member types. I certainly don’t think you want to provide that functionality to users. I don’t think you are making a library whose purpose is to detect _id static data members and CType member types.
I would suggest that what you really want is not just “a type that has an _id static data member”. I would suggest there is something semantically-meaningful that you are looking for, and the ID data member is just a proxy for that semantic. I don’t know what that semantic is, because I don’t know the use case.
Let me put it a different way. Suppose I was making a game somewhat like “The Sims”, and I had a type that encoded the Freudian characteristics of the simulated characters:
struct freudian_characteristics
{
    static int _superego;
    static int _ego;
    static int _id;
}

Now this type satisfies the type trait “has an _id static data member”… but I don’t think it is what you really want. This type has a static data member for an id… but an id (rhymes with “bid”) is not the same as an ID (rhymes with “Heidi”). You want a type that has an _id static data member, sure… and you want the type to mean something specific (like, maybe, that the type can be (de)serialized). That is what your concept is… not merely “has an _id static data member”. “Has an _id static data member” is just the mechanism you are using to identify the semantic you want.
(We’ll deal with the false positives/negatives problem later.)
As for CType, perhaps the concept there is QueryOperation or QueryModifier or something like that.
I would suggest that HasID and HasCType are implementation details, that should not (normally) be exposed to the user. Let’s put a pin in the idea of implementation details, and add some more guidelines.
3. Ideally, prefer first to build concepts only out of concepts and-ed together
The reason is that only concepts can be normalized and subsumed, so you if you use anything other than concepts, you may be unable to get ordering of constraints.
For example:
template <typename> inline constexpr auto C1 = true;
template <typename> inline constexpr auto C2 = true;

template <typename T>
requires C1<T>
auto foo() { return 0; }

template <typename T>
requires C1<T> and C2<T>
auto foo() { return 1; }

foo<int>(); // error, ambiguous

If you make C2 a concept:
template <typename> inline constexpr auto C1 = true;
template <typename> concept C2 = true;

template <typename T>
requires C1<T>
auto foo() { return 0; }

template <typename T>
requires C1<T> and C2<T>
auto foo() { return 1; }

foo<int>(); // error, still ambiguous

But if you make both C1 and C2 concepts:
template <typename> concept C1 = true;
template <typename> concept C2 = true;

template <typename T>
requires C1<T>
auto foo() { return 0; }

template <typename T>
requires C1<T> and C2<T>
auto foo() { return 1; }

foo<int>(); // fine, returns 1

Now, technically, if you make C1 a concept, then it doesn’t matter if C2 is a concept. Concepts are parsed left-to-right, so C1 will be “subsumed into itself” (C1 implies C1, obvs). With concepts… and only with concepts… the compiler recognizes identical expressions as “identical”; not merely “the same”, but IDENTICAL. In both the first and second version of foo(), if C1 is a concept—and only if C1 is a concept—then the C1<T> in both versions is recognized as “identical”. If the C1<T> in both C1<T> and C1<T> and C2<T> is identical, the compiler sees them as C1₁<T> and C1₁<T> and C2<T> then the only difference between them is the and C2<T> part in the second one, which means it subsumes the first one (C1 and C2 implies C1), and thus the second one is more constrained.
But if C1 is not a concept, then the compiler does not recognize the C1<T> in C1<T> and C1<T> and C2<T> as identical. They may be the same, but they are not identical. So the compiler can’t recognize that C1₁<T> is more or less constrained than C1₂<T> and C2<T>.
That’s a lot of complexity that comes from introducing non-concepts, and we’re only talking about one concept and one non-concept. That is why it’s easier to say just use all concepts.
And if and is the only operation combining concepts, then it is easy to understand which constraint sets are more constrained. All you need to do is remove the common subsets, and see if one is now empty while the other has stuff left. For example, if you have concepts C₁<T> through C₉<T>, and one constraint set is C₆<T> and C₂<T> and C₄<T> and the other is C₃<T> and C₄<T> and C₂<T> and C₉<T> and C₆<T> and C₅<T>, you simply remove the common subset (C₂<T>, C₄<T> and C₆<T>), and now the first one is empty while the second still has C₃<T>, C₅<T> and C₉<T>, therefore the second subsumes the first and the two constraint sets are ordered, and the second is more constrained.
So if you stick to using only concepts, and you only and them together, you get the full power of concepts, and everything is easy to understand.
3(b). … followed by only concepts and-ed, or-ed, or grouped by parentheses
But if only it were that simple.
In reality, it will often be impractical to just and all your concepts together. Sometimes you just gotta or. And once you start mixing and and or, you usually need parentheses to force precedence.
That’s all fine; constraint subsumption and ordering still works just fine with or and parentheses. It just gets a lot more complicated. Even with just two constraints, it’s less intuitive than with just and. No one seems to have any trouble understanding that C1<T> and C2<T> is more constrained than just C1<T> (or C2<T>). But people seem to have more difficulty grasping that both C1<T> and C2<T> are more constrained than C1<T> or C2<T>. In order from least to most constrained:

A or B
A or B (tie)
A and B

It makes sense if you think about it… but you may have to stop and really think about it to get it to sink in.
If there really isn’t going to be much ordering of constraints involved, then using or (and parentheses) is totally harmless. It just makes it harder to understand the ordering, so if that’s not really going to be happening… then, meh.
What you want to avoid, though, is using not, or using non-concepts. These all break normalization and subsumption. Again, if there is never going to be any need for subsumption or ordering… then it’s not really a problem. If you must build up more complex concepts with negation and non-concepts, then fine… but it is usually possible to avoid that, so at least try to.
4. It is okay to make non-semantic concepts as implementation details
So we’ve got a bit of a pickle. I said that concepts should have semantics, but I also said that you should build concepts by and-ing together only concepts. What if you want to build concepts out of type traits?
Let’s consider a concept that you might use: QueryOperation. Your query operation requires a CType member type. I don’t see any other obvious syntactic requirements, but let’s just pretend it also requires the _id static data member. So your QueryOperation concept could be built as:
template <typename T>
struct HasCType : std::bool_constant<requires { typename T::CType; }> {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto HasCType_v = HasCType<T>::value;

template <typename T>
struct HasID : std::bool_constant<requires { T::_id; }> {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto HasID_v = HasID<T>::value;

template <typename T>
concept QueryOperation = HasCType_v<T> and HasID_v<T>;

But, hang on, we’re supposed to build concepts out of concepts, so we should do:
template <typename T>
concept HasCType = requires { typename T::CType; };

template <typename T>
concept HasID = requires { T::_id; };

template <typename T>
concept QueryOperation = HasCType<T> and HasID<T>;

Except the two concepts—HasCType and HasID—are both concepts without meaningful semantics.
So… what to do?
I’m going to distinguish between public concepts—concepts intended to be used by, interacted with, or directly seen by the user—versus concepts that are merely being used as implementation details. If a concept is merely an implementation detail, then it’s fine if it has no semantics. You should always prefer concepts unless they are the wrong tool… and for implementation details it doesn’t really matter what tool you use, so, you should prefer concepts even if they would be “wrong” when not merely an implementation detail.
If HasCType and HasID were part of the public API of your library, they should be type traits. If they are not public… make them whatever you please. And since you are using them to build concepts, then making them concepts is a good idea.
5. Allow opting in/out of concepts
So concepts are meant to have semantic meaning over and above the mere syntax they actually check for. The upshot of that is that you can get cases where something satisfies a concept syntactically, but not semantically.
You can actually see examples of this right in the standard library. Most of the concepts in the standard library are all about the syntax—that’s just the nature of things with the standard library. Thus, for most standard library concepts, there can be no situation where a type satisfies a concept syntactically but fails to satisfy it semantically (because most standard library concept semantics are wholly syntactic). But there are a few exceptions! There is no syntactic difference between an input iterator and a forward iterator (let’s ignore the iterator tag for now). But they mean very different things, and they even have different observable behaviour in practice… just, you can’t see that difference merely from the syntax. There’s also std::invocable and std::regular_invocable; no syntatic difference, but a very important semantic difference.
So how do you make concepts safer? That is, how do you guard against false positives when syntax matches, but semantics don’t.
I suggest that you should make any non-trivial concept explicitly opt-in or opt-out, or (in rare cases), both.
Let’s consider the suggested QueryOperation concept. We are assuming a query operation requires a CType member type, and _id static data member. We could write the concept simply as:
template <typename T>
concept QueryOperation =
    requires
    {
        T::_id;
        typename T::CType;
    }
;

… and this is probably fine, because it is unlikely for a type to have both CType and _id and not be intended as a query operation.
Unlikely, but not impossible.
So you need to consider whether you want this concept to apply by default to anything that satisfies the syntactic constraints. I would suggest that for this concept, that’s unwise. A query operation is such a specialized thing, it seems gratuitous to want to catch everything that sorta-kinda looks the part. Instead, it makes more sense for anything that wants to be considered to be a query operation to explicitly declare itself as such.
For example:
// Nothing is a query operation unless it opts in to being one.
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto is_query_operation = false;

template <typename T>
concept QueryOperation =
    requires
    {
        T::_id;
        typename T::CType;
    }
    and is_query_operation<T>
;

struct non_query_op_type
{
    using CType = int;
    ObjectID    _id;
    int         value;
};

struct query_op_type
{
    using CType = int;
    ObjectID    _id;
    int         value;
};

template <>
inline constexpr auto is_query_operation<query_op_type> = true;

static_assert(QueryOperation<query_op_type>);
static_assert(not QueryOperation<non_query_op_type>);

Opting in is the strategy that probably works best for this case. And sure, once you opt in, the other syntax checks theoretically become redundant (who would set is_query_operation<T> to true for a type and not add _id and CType to the class?), but in practice they’re still very useful for detecting mistakes (oops, mispelled CType as Ctype!). So even if you include an opt-in mechanism, you should still do all the syntax checks.
And this is actually a strategy the standard library uses. As I said, most standard library concepts are purely syntactic in nature… but not all! For example, there is std::enable_view, and std::enable_borrowed_subrange.
An alternative strategy is opting out. This would be useful for concepts that are intended to catch a whole lot, but still not necessarily everything. For example, an integer could try to detect types that support all the mathematical operations, including % and << (which floating point numbers do not support). But there could be some types out there that also support all the standard mathematical operations, including % and <<, but are not integers. For example, maybe there is a matrix class for which % is defined as the cross product and << does some sort of transpose or something. That would be a treacherous type, so it behooves the designer to take responsibility for making sure it doesn’t get accidentally recognized as an integer, but this is not something that should happen commonly. Thus, it would make sense for the integer concept to include an opt-out, and for that matrix class to use it.
Even the standard library has some opt-out concepts, like with std::disable_sized_sentinel_for.
It may even be a good idea to provide both opt-in and opt-out. That should not be normal practice, but I have come across at least one situation where it seemed wise. I have a character concept that is supposed to detect character types. It naturally picks up all the standard character types… but I wanted to allow the possibility of non-standard character types. Like, maybe a system has a ebcdic_char_t type. At the same time, someone might have a good reason to not want a standard character type to be recognized; maybe char8_t or wchar_t is hopelessly broken on some system. So my character concept has both the ability to opt-in and opt-out:
template <typename>
inline constexpr auto enable_character_concept = false;

template <typename>
inline constexpr auto disable_character_concept = false;

template <typename T>
concept character =
    (
        std::same_as<char, T>
        or std::same_as<char8_t, T>
        or std::same_as<char16_t, T>
        or std::same_as<char32_t, T>
        or std::same_as<wchar_t, T>
        or enable_character_concept<T>
    )
    and not disable_character_concept<T>
;

But I think that is only concept I have ever written that does both opt-in and opt-out. In general, only one or the other makes sense.
You’ll note that I not only use or in there, I even use non-constraints and a not. I don’t think it’s a big deal in that case, because there doesn’t seem to be a conceivable situation where there will ever be a constraint ordering situation with only part of this concept. In other words, I don’t see it likely that there will be a situation where one thing is constrained as character and another thing is constrained as same_as<char> or same_as<char8_t>. More likely one thing will be constrained as character, and the other will be character and (same_as<char> or same_as<char8_t>… which would work fine.
(I could have made enable_character_concept a concept itself, and turned disable_character_concept into a concept excluded_from_character_concept, added a level of indirection for specialization (because concepts can’t be specialized), and then been able to do all concepts, with only ands and ors (and parentheses). But both enable_character_concept and disable_character_concept are part of the public interface, so it would be wrong if they were concepts and not configurable boolean constants. And adding extra layers of indirection seemed silly for a concept that isn’t meant to be partially ordered, but only ordered atomically.)
Applying the guidelines
Unfortunately, without more context, I cannot offer concrete advice. Even with the context I do have, quite a bit of it is really dealer’s choice: you’re the library designer, you get to decide what the semantic components are. For the sake of illustration, I will make some assumptions.
So, here is where we start:
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  struct HasID
  {
      using One = char;
      struct Two { char x[2]; };

      template <typename C> static One testHasID( decltype(C::_id)* );
      template <typename C> static Two testHasID(...);

      static constexpr bool val = sizeof(testHasID<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
  };    

  template<typename T>
  struct HasCType
  {
      using One = char;
      struct Two { char x[2]; };

      template <typename C> static One testHasType(typename C::CType*);
      template <typename C> static Two testHasType(...);

      static constexpr bool val = sizeof(testHasType<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
  };
}

GUIDELINE 1: Always prefer concepts over type traits unless you are literally just testing for type features
You are literally just testing for type features in the code above, but I propose that is not what you intend. What you intend is to detect valid query… “parts”… or “operations” or “components”. Or maybe to detect types that know how to serialize/deserialize themselves (“serializable” may sound like a bad concept in the same vein as “addable”, but I would argue that being serializable is more than just a structural property—when a type is “serializable” it does more than just support the serializable interface… it also round-trips successfully when using that interface). Or whatever.
So I would suggest that what you really want are not these type traits. Instead, there is some concept or concepts that are what you are really after, and these type traits are just a means to that end.
But, okay, let’s consider the code. These two things are just testing for type features, so they should be left as type traits. They could, however, be rewritten to use requires:
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  struct HasID
  {
      static constexpr bool val = requires { T::_id };
  };    

  template<typename T>
  struct HasCType
  {
      static constexpr bool val = requires { typename T::CType; };
  };
}

GUIDELINE 2: Concepts should be about semantics, not syntax
This follows from the previous point. I think what you really want is a concept or concepts that have some meaningful semantics… not this simple syntactic stuff.
Which also implies that you don’t just want concept-ified versions of these type traits. Your concepts are something more, even if that “more” is just semantics and not syntax.
I’ll have to just imagine some concepts for the sake of illustration, but you should know what conceptual concepts you need.
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  struct HasID
  {
      static constexpr bool val = requires { T::_id };
  };    

  template<typename T>
  struct HasCType
  {
      static constexpr bool val = requires { typename T::CType; };
  };

  template<typename T>
  concept Serializable = HasID<T>::val;

  template<typename T>
  concept QueryOperation = HasCType<T>::val;
}

GUIDELINE 3: Ideally, prefer first to build concepts only out of concepts and-ed together, followed by only concepts and-ed, or-ed, or grouped by parentheses
Given the simplicity of the concepts above, there’s not really anything to do here. Although, we should try to make HasID and HasCType concepts, that would violate guideline 2, so let’s put a pin in that.
GUIDELINE 4: It is okay to make non-semantic concepts as implementation details
And, it’s already time to pull the pin.
HasID and HasCType don’t appear to be intended as part of the public interface. That means they can be considered implementation details. And that means it doesn’t matter that there’s no real semantics, we can (and should) still make them concepts:
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  concept HasID = requires { T::_id };

  template<typename T>
  concept HasCType = requires { typename T::CType; };

  template<typename T>
  concept Serializable = HasID<T>;

  template<typename T>
  concept QueryOperation = HasCType<T>;
}

Although it doesn’t really seem to matter, this means we now get full subsumption and ordering support.
GUIDELINE 5: Allow opting in/out of concepts
Now, “serializable” is a concept that seems like it should be broadly and automatically applied wherever it can be; there doesn’t seem to be a good reason not to consider a type as serializable if it is possible for it to be serialized.
And yet….
Some types may really make no sense in a serialization context, and even attempting to (de)serialize them may be wildly wrong-headed.
That all implies that Serializable should be “on by default” wherever it can be, but explicitly opt-out.
By contrast, a Mongo query operation is a very narrow notion. Even if something happens to match the syntactic requirements, it seems a bit gratuitous to just assume it is a Mongo query operation.
That implies that QueryOperation should be opt-in.
So:
namespace ThorsAnvil::DB::Mongo
{    
  template<typename T>
  concept HasID = requires { T::_id };

  template<typename T>
  concept HasCType = requires { typename T::CType; };

  template <typename>
  inline constexpr auto DisableSerialization = false;

  template<typename T>
  concept Serializable =
      HasID<T>
      and not DisableSerialization<T>
  ;

  template <typename>
  inline constexpr auto IsQueryOperation = false;

  template<typename T>
  concept QueryOperation =
      HasCType<T>
      and IsQueryOperation<T>
  ;
}

Happy coding!

Thanks. I will read all of this. But this may take time to work through.

Do you have a recommendation for a book that explains the syntax of concepts.

I’m afraid not. The only source I’ve been using so far is cppreference.

Time for us to write one then :-)
